# problema al realizar update mysqli php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un problema con el update con php y mysql, no funciona ejecuto y no me actualiza los valores de la tabla de bd.

El código es el siguiente:

html:

```
<form action="actualizar.php" method="POST">
  <h2><em>Actualizacion de Institucion</em></h2>  

      <label for="cod_institucion">Codigo Institucion: </label>
      <input type="text" name="cod_institucion" class="form-input" required/>

      <label for="nombre_institucion">Nombre Institucion: </label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre_institucion" class="form-input" required/> 

      <label for="sector_cod_sector">Codigo Sector: </label>
      <input type="text" name="sector_cod_sector" class="form-input" required/>

      <center> <input class="form-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Actualizar Institucion" /></center>
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pw = "";
$db = "proyecto";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pw, $db) or die("no se pudo conectar");

$cod_institucion = $_POST['cod_institucion'];
$nombre_institucion = $_POST['nombre_institucion'];
$sector_cod_sector = $_POST['sector_cod_sector'];

$actualizar =  "UPDATE institucion set nombre_institucion = '$nombre_institucion', sector_cod_sector = '$sector_cod_sector' where cod_institucion = '$cod_institucion'";

$resultado =mysqli_query($con, $actualizar) or die("error al actualizar datos");
?>
```

actualizacion: el unico error que me lanza el navegador al ejecutar el codigo es: 
Notice: Undefined index: cod_institucion in C:\wamp64\www\proyectos\administrador\actualizar.php on line 9
me da ese mismo error en las lineas 10 y 11

actualizacion: 
Hice el print_r($_POST); que me recomendaron, y me arroja lo siguiente:
Array ( [cod_inst] => policia [nombre_inst] => pacos [cod_sector] => 2 [submit] => Actualizar Institucion )

Lo demas no lo entiendo, llevo horas intentando reparar esto, con los datos que me dieron abajo y no logro hacer que funcione, soy primerizo en lo que es php con mysql.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema exactamente? ¿No hace la modificación?  ¿Levanta algún tipo de error? Si ejecutas las consulta generada directamente en base de datos... ¿Funciona?

Comment: Por favor, escribe el codigo del formulario que utilizas. Recuerda que tiene que estar en metodo POST (ya que en tu php recojes los parametros con $_POST). El error es que los indices esos no existen. Puede ser porque no se envian correctamente. Puedes mirar antes el resultado con un **print_r($_POST);** para ver lo que llega a tu php

Comment: Supongo que tu html está en un archivo php diferente de `actualizar.php` y que ambos se encuentran en la misma carpeta. Es posible que sea un problema de rutas de archivos, ya que tu actual archivo no está recibiendo los datos que estás enviando desde el formulario. Por otra parte, tu consulta de UPDATE está escrita usando una **muy mala práctica de programación**. Nunca escribas consultas así: `$actualizar =  "UPDATE institucion set nombre_institucion = '$nombre_institucion', sector_cod_sector = '$sector_cod_sector' where cod_institucion = '$cod_institucion'";`, **usa consultas preparadas**

Comment: Revisa que si estes recibiendo los datos de tu formulario antes de actualizarlo.

Answer (score 1):

**Tu mismo te respondiste.**

En el `update` pones que `where cod_institucion = '$cod_institucion'` pero al inicializar esta variable te está diciendo que no se la estás envíando por `POST` y que no se puede inicializar.

Estás leyendo directamente las variables `POST`y lo estás colocando en la consulta, esto es un [`agujero de seguridad`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agujero_de_seguridad), ya que pueden intentar manipularte la consulta en esa petición. Revisa este enlace para almenos escapar las comillas: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php.

PD: Revisa que no estés enviando por `GET` en vez de `POST`, quizás ese sea tu problema.

Comment: ¡Cuidado! El agujero de seguridad no se resuelve con real escape, sino usando consultas preparadas.

Comment: Lo se, pero mejor que nada es, si lo normal sería usar PDO no mysqli, pero dado el código doy por sentado que está empezando, primero es entender que no puedes cojer directamente de post o get tan alegramente y usarlo, mucho menos en una consulta SQL. Edité un poco el mensaje para corregir esto que remarcaste.

Answer (score 0):

> Notice: Undefined index: cod_institucion

esto lo unico que significa es que no esta definido en la posicion que dices... Mira si el array no empieza asi:

remplazar

```
$_POST['cod_institucion'];
```

por

```
$_POST['cod_inst'];
```

al menos veo que dices que eso te dice el `print_r` segun tu comentario. Y hacerlo con cada uno.

y si fuera tu persona lo hiciera asi:

```
$actualizar =  "UPDATE institucion set nombre_institucion = 
'{$nombre_institucion}', sector_cod_sector = '{$sector_cod_sector}' where 
cod_institucion = '{$cod_institucion}'";
```

Y aunque es una mala practica realmente. Se entiende eres principiante te recomiendo luego de solucinar esto buscar documentacion acerca de estos temas.